# How to get all dates for a given year and calendar week in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, calendar

Say you have a year "2017" and an isocalendar week "13". How would you get all dates corresponding to this year and calendar week efficiently (with use of a library like datetime or calendar) as a list in Python?

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your previous research?

Comment: I tried `first_date_of_CW = datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-13', '%Y-%W')` with the following alternatives for W: U, w, V, v. The idea: obtain the first (or any other) day of the calendar week in order to then calculate the other days with datetime.timedelta. However, it does not seem like one can just convert 'year-cw' to a date.

Comment: If you know the ordinal of the first day of week 1, then add `7*13` to get the ordinal for the start of week 13...

Comment: Good idea but that gets tricky. E.g. for 2017, the first isocalendar week starts on the 2nd of January (see http://whatweekisit.org/calendar-2017.html). This keeps changing across years. My questions is asked under the assumption that I don't know the first day of the first calendar week (yet).

Answer (score 1):

This ought to do it.

```py
import datetime
def get_month (year: int, weekday: int):
    start = datetime.datetime (year=year, month=1, day=1)
    '''
    Weekday correction:
    source: https://www.calendar-week.org/
    "In Europe, the first calendar week of the year is the week that
    contains four days of the new year."
    '''
    if start.weekday () >= 4:
        start += datetime.timedelta (days=7-start.weekday ())
    else:
        start -= datetime.timedelta (days=start.weekday ())
    start += datetime.timedelta (days=7*(weekday-1))
    return [start + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range (0, 7)]
```

Will return a list of `datetime`-s. To get string representation:

```py
print (list (map (lambda x: str (x.date()), get_month (2017, 2))))
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks good. However, for 2017, I am getting weeks that start with a Sunday, for 2018 weeks that start with Monday, for 2019 weeks that start with a Tuesday etc. Why would that be?

Comment: @jollycat  Oh, count it as a bug. January 1 is not guaranteed to be a Sunday.  The two lines counting backswords fix it.

Comment: This relates to the problem that I mentioned in the very top comments below the question. In 2017, the first isocalendar week starts with a Sunday, in 2018, the first isocalendar week starts with a Monday, in 2019 the first isocalendar week starts with a Tuesday. You can, of course, hard code this pattern but that would not really be nice and reliable (considering leap years).

Comment: Well just go back until the first Sunday/Monday (depending on what weekday 0 means) and count 7 days from there. The 4th line fixes the issue.

Comment: However, how about leap years? This changes by +2 in leap years (instead of +1).

Comment: As we do calculation using `datetime`, the leap year fuss is taken care off. @jollycat

Comment: @jollycat give an example of incorrect output, and I'll look into it.

Comment: e.g. for get_month(2096, 1) you get a week that has 6 days from 2095 (not 2096). So, it seems like the result is off by a full week. See this for comparison: https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=2096&country=21 or https://www.week-number.org/calendar-weeks-2096.html. Note that 2096 is a leap year (see https://kalender-365.de/leap-years.php). However, this does not seem to be an issue w.r.t. leap years. A similar issue occurs with the year before, 2095.

Comment: Well, `In Europe, the first calendar week of the year is the week that contains four days of the new year.`. This is dumb, but doable.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is what you want. I played around with `calendar` module and this is the best I managed to do, let me know:

```
import calendar

def get_week(y, w):
    weeks  = [
        tuple(w) 
        for t in cal.yeardatescalendar(y) for month in t for w in month
        if w[0].year == y
    ]
    weeks = sorted(list(set(weeks)))
    return list(weeks[w-1])
get_week(2017, 13)
```

Output:

```
[datetime.date(2017, 3, 27),
 datetime.date(2017, 3, 28),
 datetime.date(2017, 3, 29),
 datetime.date(2017, 3, 30),
 datetime.date(2017, 3, 31),
 datetime.date(2017, 4, 1),
 datetime.date(2017, 4, 2)]
```

Or with `datetime.isocalendar()` function:

```
import datetime as dt

def get_week(y, w):
    first = next(
        (dt.date(y, 1, 1) + dt.timedelta(days=i) 
         for i in range(367)
         if (dt.date(y, 1, 1) + dt.timedelta(days=i)).isocalendar()[1] == w))
    return [first + dt.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(7)]

get_week(2017, 13)
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks good! It also solves the issue with `get_month(2096, 1)` that I had with @hingev 's solution.